Does JProfiler's Net I/O and Waiting Thread operations involve low CPU load? Is there a relationship between CPU usage and Runnable thread time?
Our team is currently running stress tests and using JProfiler for monitoring.
We chose two scenarios for the test: setting concurrent threads to 10 and 40, and then compared the results.
The test results were recorded using Async Sampling for both JPA views and HTTP Server views.
We made a few discoveries:

CPU usage showed a significant difference: with 10 threads, it ranged from 15-30%, while with 40 threads, it ranged from 40-70%.
(Image shows the results of performing the same stress test four times) And the  server is configured with 1 CPU core.




Comparing 10 threads to 40 threads, the time spent in runnable thread time is about the same, whether observed in JPA views or HTTP Server views.

JPA views

HTTP Server views


In both test scenarios, Net I/O takes time, but 40 threads consume more time than 10 threads, whether observed in JPA views or HTTP Server views.

JPA views

HTTP Server views


When the number of threads is 10, there is no Waiting thread time, but there is Waiting thread time when it is 40, whether observed in JPA views or HTTP Server views.

JPA views

HTTP Server views

I referred to the following resources (the issue pertains to an earlier version of JProfiler):

java - What is Jprofiler9 NetIO state really mean? - Stack Overflow

It's tracking network calls. It could be part of the waiting state, but that would be less useful.
There is usually a low CPU load in this thread state.



The answer explains that the Net I/O thread state should involve low CPU load operations. Is this correct? And is the Waiting thread state also a low CPU load operation?
If both are correct, it implies that the CPU should be consumed elsewhere, such as in the runnable thread state (with block thread time approaching zero, I think it can be ignored).
So why is there such a large difference in CPU usage between 10 threads and 40 threads, even though Runnable thread time is about the same?
Thank you all for your time and help!

It's really difficult to answer such a question, because everything depends on what your test does and it also depends on the hardware. With async profiling, the thread state is actually called "Running" (you can see that in the thread state selector) because it measures threads while they are actually being scheduled. With regular sampling it's called "Runnable" because that is the thread state where they can be scheduled for execution. In both modes the total times are quite different.

Based on the answer to this question, Net I/O might not be a low CPU operation. Is my opinion right? @IngoKegel

And based on your comment, async profiling can provide more accurate execution times. We're using this method, but comparing 10 threads and 40 threads shows no significant difference in actual execution (Runnable) time, yet the CPU usage is different. In this case...

How else can we use JProfiler to make more detailed observations?
Or are there any other angles or directions we can consider or explore to explain this?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@CheZY JProfiler is concerned with Java method executions. Underlying performance conditions like context switches, cache hits etc. cannot be analyzed further with JProfiler.


why is there such a large difference in CPU usage between 10 threads and 40
threads

Context switches are expensive operations and depending on the number of cores, the function of CPU usage per thread count jumps at some point.
